# My notification was replace by the lastest one

Tags: android, notifications

My problem is my todo schedule was replace by the lastest one (notification will work only for the last one if i enter multiple todos same time) I already check that notification id isn't same please help.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.todo_add);
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    stdid = pref.getString("std_id", null)+"Notification.txt";
    System.out.println(stdid);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    fileName = intent.getStringExtra("fileName");
    items = new ArrayList<>();
    spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    topic = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.topic);
    desc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.todoDesc);
    todoTime =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    todoDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date todo_time = new Date();
    todo_time.setHours(mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    todo_time.setMinutes(mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    todoTime.setText(df.format(todo_time));
    todoDate.setText(mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"/"+mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+
            mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        topic.requestFocus();
    todoTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(Todo_Add.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    if(selectedMinute<=9) {
                        todoTime.setText(selectedHour + ":0" + selectedMinute);
                    }else{
                        todoTime.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                    }
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);
            mTimePicker.show();

        }
    });
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    todoDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DateDialog();
        }
    });
    todoDate.setFocusable(false);
    todoDate.setClickable(true);
}






public void onClickAddTodo(View view) {
    category = String.valueOf(spin.getSelectedItem());
    if(topic.length()>0) {
        writeItems();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Todo_List.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Todo_Add.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert: No Topic");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please Enter Topic.");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        topic.requestFocus();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}


public void DateDialog(){

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth)
        {

            todoDate.setText(dayOfMonth+" / "+monthOfYear+" / "+year);

        }};

    DatePickerDialog dpDialog=new DatePickerDialog(this, listener, year, month, day);
    dpDialog.show();

}


public void onClickBack(View v) {
    todoTime.setText("");
    todoDate.setText("");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Todo_List.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void readItems() {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    File todoFile = new File(filesDir, fileName);
    items = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(todoFile);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        items = (ArrayList<todoObj>)ois.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void writeItems() {
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    File todoFile = new File(filesDir, fileName);
    try {
        readItems();
        temp = new todoObj();
        temp.setTopic(topic.getText().toString());
        temp.setDesc(desc.getText().toString());
        temp.setCategory(category);
        temp.setDate(Util.getDateFromEditText(todoDate,todoTime));
        items.add(temp);
        Collections.sort(items);
        ObjectOutputStream ois = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(todoFile));
        ois.writeObject(items);

        /*Setup Notification*/
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date dateFuture = temp.getDate();
        dateFuture.setYear(dateFuture.getYear()-1900);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date dateNow = c.getTime();
        if(dateFuture.getTime()>dateNow.getTime()){
            String future = dateFormat.format(dateFuture);
            String title = temp.getTopic();
            String content = temp.getDesc();
            if(temp.isFinish()==false) {
                scheduleNotification(getNotification(title, content), getSchedule(getTimeCurrent(), future));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getTimeCurrent() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    String sDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    return sDate;
}

private void readNoti(){
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    File todoFile = new File(filesDir, stdid);
    NotiItems = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(todoFile);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        NotiItems = (ArrayList<NotificationObj>)ois.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void writeNoti(NotificationObj obj){
    File filesDir = getFilesDir();
    File notiFile = new File(filesDir, stdid);
    try{
        readNoti();
        NotiItems.add(obj);
        Collections.sort(NotiItems);
        ObjectOutputStream ois = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(notiFile));
        ois.writeObject(NotiItems);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private long getSchedule(String now, String future) {
    long TimeDifference = 0;
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date dNow = df.parse(future);
        Date dFuture = df.parse(now);
        TimeDifference = ((dNow.getTime() - dFuture.getTime())+500);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return TimeDifference;
}
private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, long delay) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
}


private Notification getNotification(String title,String content) {
    temp = new todoObj();       //start
    temp.setTopic(topic.getText().toString());
    temp.setDesc(desc.getText().toString());
    temp.setCategory(category);
    temp.setDate(Util.getDateFromEditText(todoDate,todoTime));
    NotificationObj noti = new NotificationObj(temp);
    writeNoti(noti);        //stop
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Todo_View.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", (Parcelable) temp);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Todo_View.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
            .build();
    return notification;
}
```

}

Comment: Your PendingIntent has always the same requestCode (zero).
 `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`. Change it for different requests

Comment: please explain me more about this parameters to make me understand how to set this code to different request code thank you very much @GVillani82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says about [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html):

> A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent
>   objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents,
>   expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not
>   happen.

This is way if you want create two different PendingIntents active at the same time you need to distinguish them.

> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at
>   the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown
>   at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something
>   that is different about them to associate them with different
>   PendingIntents

One way for doing it is to use a different `requestCode` in the method:

```
getBroadcast (Context context, 
                int requestCode, 
                Intent intent, 
                int flags)
```

In this way the PendingIntents will be considered different.